# How to select posts from database that contain certain word?

Tags: php, sql

I'm working on search on my website and I would like to select posts from database that contain word (or words) that user searched.
I'm using code below and it works, but since I'm using LIMIT 10, it can happen that in 10 selected posts, for example, only 2 posts contain searched word, so only 2 posts will be displayed, even if there are more posts in database that contain searched words.

```
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
while($posts_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($posts )) {
...
$post_body = $posts_row ['post_body'];
if (strstr($post_body, $search)) {
 echo $post_body;
}
...
}
```

Is there a way to only select posts from database that contain searched word? 
Something like

```
$posts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE strstr($post_body, $search) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10");
```

EDIT: Thank you for your help and advices.

Comment: be sure to read about sql injection. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: use LIKE in your query.

eg. 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_body LIKE %$search%';

Comment: mysql_* functions are bad! They are being deprecated. Take a look at mysqli or PDO

Comment: @axrwkr Is strip_tags good to prevent SQL injection or do I need to use mysqli_real_escape_string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (tested in MySQL , am not sure for others):

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_body LIKE ( '%".$search."%' ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"
```

Answer (score 1):

First:  Don't use mysql_ - it's deprecated and is being phased out for security reasons.  Use mysqli_ instead.

Second:  Use 'like' to do so:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE columnName LIKE '%keyword%';
```

Will find matches in data values of `'keyword searches are fun'` also `'Find this keyword'` and `'all keywords are words.'`

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `LIKE` to do this search.

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE post_body LIKE ('%?%') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Here `post_body` would be whatever filed stores the post content and `?` would be replaced by your search string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as a query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE $post_body like '%$search%' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

This is probably very limiting and slow though. Depending on how big your application and how much data you have, you might want to give "Full-Text Search".
[Full-Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//fulltext-search.html)